# access 2013 accesing sharepoint lists hangs, why?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, microsoft-access

I have downloaded Access 2013 from my office365 account and I'm trying to use it to edit linked lists in a different SharePoint site (not office365), I can create the linked tables but when exiting this access 2013 database access hangs and when I try to use it again it holds and do nothing until I restart Access.

Note : I have tested the same solution with Office 2010 professional and it works like a charm.

anyone knows why?

Comment: did you try to run Access 2013 as an Administrator? Also make sure your Access is upto date, if not apply the latest CU.

Comment: I run it as admin, what I have found is that if I open the access and click on refresh list, it ask me for credentials and then works, it seems that it doesnt try to reconnect when starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I created a macro that refresh the lists and save it as autoexec and it executes at start.